# Как удалить все кроме одной строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Если есть переменная text как можно из этой переменной удалить все строки кроме 19 строки (всего 54 строки) и в оставшийся 19 строке удалить первые 36 символов? ничего в интернете не нашел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = text.splitlines()[18][36:]
```